# Creating & sending JSON from client to server, and expected result

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I'm trying to parse user input from my webpage and store it in a JSON object using inline JavaScript, make a `POST` request to my Node.js server, and access the contents of the request.

In my `example.html`, I have a function which does the following:

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
dataToSubmit = [];

// find some inputs

for ( /* each row of input */ ) {
    dataToSubmit.push({
                        'item': itemName,
                        'quantity': quantity,
                        'price': itemPrice
                     });
}

xhttp.open("POST", "http://localhost:8080/menu", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
xhttp.send(JSON.stringify(dataToSubmit));
```

---

### EDIT :

After the `POST` request, I have a `dispatcher.js` file that processes the requests:

```
function(request, response) {
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var requestBody = '';
    request.on('data', function(data) { requestBody += data; });
    request.on('end', function() {
        var qs = require('querystring');
        var passed_data = qs.parse(requestBody);

        if(request.url === "/menu") {
            var menu_handler = require("./menu.js");
            menu_handler.processOrder(passed_data);
    }
}
```

---

I'm exporting `processOrder()` from my `menu.js`. The issue is that on the server-side, I have to do the following in order to access the object:

```
processOrder: function(data) {
    for (var a in data) { <-------------- Having to do this seems incorrect
        // a is a string, inputs is the expected object
        var inputs = JSON.parse(a); 
    }
}
```

My question is: is the way I'm creating the JSON object incorrect, or is the way I'm accessing it on the server-side incorrect? My expectation is that, on the server-side, I should be able to do something like this:

```
processOrder: function(data) {
    var inputs = JSON.parse(data);
    for (var input in inputs) {
        // access to input.item, input.quantity, input.price
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to provide an [mcve]. You've shown us steps 2 and 6 of your process and we have no idea what goes on in between.

Comment: Start by looking at the actual request you are sending. Use the Network tab in your browser's developer tools. Is the request body you are sending formatted the way you expect it to be? If so: Show us that and the server-side code that processes it. The client-side JS becomes irrelevent. Is it wrong? Then show us the client-side code that builds it.

Comment: We have no idea what `itemName`, `quantity` and `itemPrice` are. Your code and results suggests that they are JSON encoded data, but we can't see them.

Comment: We have no idea how data gets into `processOrder`. Presumably *something* is parsing the JSON, but we can't see what.

Comment: You're right. Forgot that I had the `querystring` module parsing all incoming requests already. Making a check for `request.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json'` and using `JSON.parse()` under this condition solved it. I couldn't tell from the Request Payload in the Network debug tool, but your last comment reminded me that I was doing parsing in a file beforehand. Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of me not being able to access the `dataToSubmit` variable as a JSON object was that I was doing parsing at a previous layer before the data reached the `processOrder` function. The solution was to make the following changes in my `dispatcher.js` file (which processes the `requestBody` before it makes its eventual way to `menu.js`):

```
function(request, response) {
    var qs = require('querystring');
    var requestBody = '';
    request.on('data', function(data) { requestBody += data; });
    request.on('end', function() {
        var qs = require('querystring');
        var passed_data;
        if(request.headers['content-type'] === 'application/json') { <--- parse JSON data
            passed_data = JSON.parse(requestBody);                   
        else {
            passed_data = qs.parse(requestBody);
        }

        if(request.url === "/menu") {
            var menu_handler = require("./menu.js");
            menu_handler.processOrder(passed_data);
    }
}
```

Furthermore, when creating the JSON object, the following needed to be done in order to access the data as a JSON object rather than as an array:

```
dataToSubmit = {'content': []};
dataToSubmit['content'].push(
    {
        'item': itemName,
        'quantity': quantity,
        'price': itemPrice
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make dataToSubmit an object:

dataToSubmit = {};

For each input row, add a uniquely keyed property to your dataToSubmit, and assign it an object:

```
dataToSubmit['keyName' + index] = {}
```

Assign this new object properties like:

```
dataToSubmit['keyName' + index]['item'] = itemName;
dataToSubmit['keyName' + index]['quantity'] = quantity;
dataToSubmit['keyName' + index]['price'] = itemPrice;
```

Comment: In conjunction with @Quentin, this solution allows me to access the `dataToSubmit` variable as a JSON object. +1